SSRS Report Go To Url not clickable
Created a custom report for D365 using VS 2022, and in the report, there is a column that will link to a URL. I have already written the expression as shown.

However, the column is still not clickable. I don’t know what went wrong.
I tried this too.
="javascript:void(window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank'))"
but still can not click it.

The link probably won't work if you are trying this from Visual Studio or Report Builder. Have you tried deploying the report to the server?

Maybe your changes aren't applied even though you did the deployment operation in Visual Studio 2022.
At least, the URL field should be blue high-light style.
You can open the report service configuration manager, delete the original SSRS, and deploy the report again.
